# How do I share an NSArrayController between two nib files?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have an array of images, and two nib files. One nib file has a window that displays the images in an NSTableView. The other nib has a window that draws the array of images into an NSView, and also draws a highlight over the images that are selected.

The array of images is controlled by an NSArrayController. I'm having trouble getting the two nibs to share the NSArrayController. I would have two separate NSArrayControllers bound to the same content, but I also want both nibs to share the controller's selection; that is, if you select an image in the table window, it also becomes selected in the other window.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would have two separate NSArrayControllers bound to the same content, but I also want both nibs to share the controller's selection; that is, if you select an image in the table window, it also becomes selected in the other window.
>
> Is there a standard way to do this?

Have two separate NSArrayControllers bound to the same content and [selection indexes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSArrayController.html#//apple_ref/occ/binding/NSArrayController/selectionIndexes).

Comment: @peter Could you elaborate on how to connect the two NSArrayControllers?

Comment: @Gavin: You don't. You just bind both controllers' content and selection-indexes bindings to the same properties of the same object.

Comment: @PeterHosey Could you please check out my similar question and carry on the comments there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356863/document-xib-contains-two-windows-one-window-needs-to-be-a-preference-panel

Comment: @PeterHosey Could you please elaborate a little more your answer ? You send via the `init` methods the `content` and `selection indexes`, and then bind them to another `NSArrayController` ?

Comment: @Colas: You have two array controllers (one in each nib), and you bind the `contentArray` and `selectionIndexes` of both of them to the same two properties of a third object (probably the FO).

Comment: @PeterHosey But what is this object ? If it is an instance (in the 2nd nib) of an object pointing the right object (in the 1st nib), is it enough ? Or, do we have to add observers ?

Comment: @Colas: Like I said, usually the FO of both nibs. Whatever object owns the content array (and, because both array controllers will need it, the set of selection indexes).